# Find all elasticsearch docs that are a parent

Tags: elasticsearch

In my index, all docs have a join field called `relation`, and are either a parent or child. The mapping looks like this:

```
"relation": {
  "type": "join",
  "eager_global_ordinals": true,
  "relations": {
    "parent": "child"
  }
},
```

The `relation` field for a doc with no children would look like this:

```
"_source": {
  "relation": {
    "name": "parent"
  },
  "children": [],
```

I want to search for all docs that are a parent, whether they have children or not. I see no examples in Elasticsearch documentation that can achieve this, so have tried this:

```
{"query": {"bool": {"must": [
  {"match":{"relation.name":"parent"}}
]}}}
```

and get no result (not surprising b/c a join field is a special case). So how might I find all parents, typically combining with other match conditions, e.g. docs with {value} in field A and a parent with or without children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find parent docs, use simply relation field name in the query, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
     "match": {
        "relation": "parent"
     }
  }
}
```

You can use the `match` query, or better a `term` query.